# How to set description string for DescriptionAttribute from json file?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I'm trying to add description to my enums, so later I can use custom method GetDescription() that returns description for specified enum.
I'd like to keep descriptions in json file for future maintaince.

Right now my enums looks like this:

```
public enum Superheroes
{
    [Description("This guy looks like bat")]
    Batman = 11,
    [Description("He's super strong")]
    Superman = 24,
    [Description("Rich engineer")]
    Ironman = 33
}
```

I'd like to have json file with structure like this:

```
{
  11: "This guy looks like bat",
  24: "He's super strong"
  33: "Rich engineer"
}
```

or like this:

```
{
  Batman: "This guy looks like bat",
  Superman: "He's super strong"
  Ironman: "Rich engineer"
}
```

And somehow map enum descriptions from json file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add attributes to a type or its members dynamically.

The best option is that in your `GetDescription()` you'd lookup the description in the JSON file, and as a fallback option resort to the `[Description]` attribute when no text is provided in the JSON.